# How to divide contents of a file with contents of another file?

Tags: linux, shell, math, awk

I have file1 which contains a single column:

```
24.5829
30.0909
26.7116
26.9422
27.9492
32.1318
35.6075
46.4325
39.6898
31.729
31.5597
35.776
...
```

I have another file2 which contains:
`Average =  36.8324`

I want to divide all the values of file1 by the average in file2 then multiply by 2 and print them into a new file3:

```
ploidy
1.33485192385 
1.63393642554 
1.45044037315
...
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service; you're expected to show your effort (eg, research, code); consider reviewing [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update the question accordingly; in particular, show the code you've tried so far and the (incorrect) output generated by your code

Comment: If you only need to show 3 lines of output to demonstrate your needs, then you only need to show 3 lines of input too. As mentioned in your previous question please provide a [mcve] with concise, testable **minimal** sample input that demonstrates your needs and exactly the output given that input. If there's too much input for you to be bothered writing the associated output as it's mostly redundant then that's too much input for us too. We can't test a potential solution without both input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk:

```bash
awk 'NR == FNR { avg = $3; print "ploidy"; next }
     { print ($0 / avg) * 2.0 }' file2 file1 > file3
```

Comment: It is useful to wait with the answer until the questioner has shown what he has done to answer the question himself.

Comment: That would produce a divide by zero error if the average in file2 was 0.